# Check if time is between two times PHP

Tags: php

From an API we get two times in this format:

```
starttime: 700
endtime:   030
```

I need to know if the current time is between those times.
But when using for example:

```
current_time = date('Gi')
```

the time could be 945. When using the if statement:

```
if(($current>= $starttime) && ($current<= $endtime))
```

This time will not be between this times. But in the real life this time
is between those two dates. Because 030 is the next day midnight.

Does somebody know how to make an right PHP check for this?

Comment: The api is wired, how did you know `030` is the next day but not the next next day or not today? when you get start for `020` and end for `030`, would that be next day too?

Comment: The endtime is always after the starttime. So if the starttime is lower than the endtime it only could be the next day. On the front-end it looks like this: 09:00 till 00:30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if `$endtime` is next day, simply add `2400` to it during the test.

```
$endtime = $endtime <= $starttime ? $endtime + 2400 : $endtime;

if ( ($current >= $starttime) && ($current <= $endtime) )
```

Comment: This solution works well! Thanks! I will accept this answer in a few minutes.